# Keep cell position in UITableView after reload

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am refreshing my UITable every couple of minutes, in case there is new data they should be added at the beginning of the table than it reloads.

```
var j = 0
let n = store?.news?.count
while(j < n!){
self.news?.insert((store?.news?[j])!, at: j)
    j = j + 1
}
```

No problem in saving the data at first positions.
The problem is i cannot keep the cell position after each reload it moving up ( the number of records added) , i have tried multiple functions but apparently it's only working in case data where added at the end of the table.

```
let contentOffset = self.tableV.contentOffset
self.tableV.reloadData()
self.tableV.contentOffset = contentOffset
```

Also i tired to save the cell position and add the count of entered data to it but this kind of addition does not work.
Is there a way to add the number of entered data which is counted , lets say N to the indexPath.row?

Comment: can you show how you add the new data to the datasource?

Comment: var j = 0
                        let n = store?.news?.count
                        while(j < n!){
                            self.news?.insert((store?.news?[j])!, at: j)
                            j = j + 1
                        }           This is the way and data are being saved at first positions. No problem in this part.

Comment: Please update your post with the code instead of pasting the code in comment section.

Comment: checkout my answer

Comment: @yasserh I think it is not possible because if you enter new data on top and reload the data then your current cell content offset has been changed so you got wrong cell at that content offset. if you add data last then it will be work

Comment: @chirag shah I know that but is it possible to update the cell index and add to it the number of data entered?

Comment: It is possible if your cell have same size then add that size in contentoffset

Comment: @chirag shah Thank you , i tried your idea and it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution to my problem . Since i have one cell size in all the table i tried this method:

```
 self.cell = 143 * CGFloat(n!)
let offset = self.tableV.contentOffset.y + self.cell!
self.tableV.reloadData()
self.tableV.contentOffset.y = offset
```

I added the number of cell entered (n) to the contentOffset and the table kept its position after reloading data.

Answer (score 7):

Actually it happens because it recalculates the `UITableViewAutomaticDimension height`.

You can solve this by storing your `cell's height` and use it to assign in `estimatedHeightForRowAt` for your cell.
Behind the scene it will assign your exact `cell's height` to `estimatedHeightForRowAt`. so recalculation won't fluctuate your tableview.

Implement as below.

```
// declare dictionary variable for storing heights of cells
var cellHeightsDictionary: [IndexPath: CGFloat] = [:]
```

Then ***store cell's height*** in your dictionary variable using tableview's method `willDisplay`  and assign those cell's height respectively in `estimatedHeightForRowAt`

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        self.cellHeightsDictionary[indexPath] = cell.frame.size.height
    }
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        if let height =  self.cellHeightsDictionary[indexPath]{
            return height
        }
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }
```

That's it. You are done.

Answer (score 2):

If you are not using constant tableview cell height, then the solution I have found is:

1- Store the top cell's unique id before reloading the new data.

```
var lastMessageIdAtTopBeforeRefreshing: String? = nil

@objc func refreshData(sender: UIRefreshControl?, event: UIEvent?) {
    self.lastMessageIdAtTopBeforeRefreshing = self.tableSectionsArray[0][0].messageId
    self.reloadData()
}
```

2- Add new rows to data source and stop decelerating the table view first:

```
self.tblChat.stopDecelerating()
UIView.performWithoutAnimation {
    self.tblChat.reloadData()
}
self.tblChat.layoutIfNeeded()

if self.lastMessageIdAtTopBeforeRefreshing != nil {
    if let findIndexPathOf = self.findIndexPathOf(messageId: self.lastMessageIdAtTopBeforeRefreshing!) {
        self.tblChat.scrollToRow(at: findIndexPathOf, at: .top, animated: false)
        self.lastMessageIdAtTopBeforeRefreshing = nil
    }
}
```

This is the extension:

```
extension UIScrollView  {
    func stopDecelerating() {
        let contentOffset = self.contentOffset
        self.setContentOffset(contentOffset, animated: false)
    }
}
```

This is my function to find the indexpath, change it as your logic.

```
func findIndexPathOf(messageId: String) -> IndexPath? {
    var i1 = 0, i2 = 0
    for sections in tableSectionsArray {
        for rows in sections {
            if rows.messageId == messageId {
                return IndexPath(row: i2, section: i1)
            }
            i2 += 1
        }
        i1 += 1
    }

    return nil
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For better Approach i think you can easily add new row in `tableview`, there is no need to reload `tableview`. so remove `self.tableV.reloadData()`

```
    var j = 0
    var arrayIndexPaths : [NSIndexPath] = []
    let n = store?.news?.count
    while(j < n!){
        self.news?.insert((store?.news?[j])!, at: j)

        let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: j, inSection: 0)
        j = j + 1
        arrayIndexPaths.append(indexPath)
    }

    // Now you have array of IndexPaths so you just insert New row like this way.

    self.tableview.beginUpdates()
    self.tableview.insertRowsAtIndexPaths(arrayIndexPaths, withRowAnimation: .None) 
    self.tableview.endUpdates()
```

**UPDate Answer**

And your `UITableViewDelegate` method like this

```
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.news?.count
    }
```

Comment: There is an error Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (42) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (42), I want to add new values so the number of rows should be 43 if i added 1 more

Comment: I tried the update , the table is not keeping position , it moving upward the number of records entered.